# Error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am attempting to make a plot using Chebyshev nodes and Lagrange polynomials shown in the following but I am receiving the error *x, y, and format string must not be None*. Why is this happening, how can I fix it/ plot what I want to appropriately?

EDIT: I have updated my code to fix the original error *x, y, and format string must not be None* and now I have the error *unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'*

```
import numpy as np

def lagrange(x, z, f):
    d = len(x)
    if len(x) != len(z):
        print("Error: the length of x and z is different")
    else:
        p = 0
        for i in range (d):
            L = 1
            for j in range (d):
                if j != i:
                    L *= (z-x[j])/(x[i] - x[j])
                p += f[i]*L
        return p
        

def f(x):
  return np.cos(x)

d = [0.1, 4, 0.2]
g = [-0.3, 0, 0.3]
lagrange(d, g, f(d))
```

Comment: the problem is that ```lagrange(d, g, f(d)) = None``` which can't be plotted

Comment: does it =None because I haven't defined my function correctly?

Comment: there are two problems with your function:  one is the input because ```len(d) = 10``` while ```len(g) = 3``` so you arrive at  ```print("Error: the length of x and z is different")``` and also it doesn't return anything, maybe you want to change the print statements with return statements but you still need to solve the input problem

Comment: I have updated my code to fix the original error x, y, and format string must not be None and now I have the error unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int, do you know why this is?

Comment: z is a list while all the others are numbers, you can't do the minus and division operations between them, but I don't know what you want to do with that piece of code so I can't help you further if you don't describe to me what it is supposed to do

Comment: I thought the for loops made lists? I gather this is not the case. Do you think I need to change x and f to lists?

Comment: my aim is to write a function that performs lagrange interpolation and takes a function f, order n, array (of any length) z and the array x with the data points for the polynomial interpolation, and returns the values pn(z) of the polynomial interpolation, then use it in a plot

Comment: I think that the answer is what you are looking for :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using np.array:

```
import numpy as np

def lagrange(x, z, f):
    d = len(x)
    if len(x) != len(z):
        print("Error: the length of x and z is different")
    else:
        p = 0
        for i in range (d):
            L = 1
            for j in range (d):
                if j != i:
                    L *= (z-x[j])/(x[i] - x[j])
                p += f[i]*L
        return p
        

def f(x):
  return np.cos(x)


d = np.array([0.1, 4, 0.2])
g = np.array([-0.3, 0, 0.3])

lagrange(d, g, f(d))
```

This will return `array([-5.08984891,  1.04582888,  6.70431625])`